# Match any char inside two quotation pairs, including nested quotations

Tags: regex, c++11, qregularexpression

I have data that will appear as dual quotation pairs like this, per line.

```
"Key" "Value"
```

Inside of these pairs there can be any character, and sometimes there comes the 
dreaded "" nested pair:

```
"Key "superkey"" ""Space" Value"
```

Previously I've found: `"([^"]*)"\s*"([^"]*)"`
And this matches Key and Value to two groups:

```
$1 = Key
$2 = Value
```

But, with the nested pairs, it will only output:

```
$1 = superkey
```

Is there a way to match all characters between the pairs? Example output wanted:

```
$1 = Key "superkey"
$2 = "Space" Value
```

Regular expression processing from QRegularExpression and c++11 Literal string:

```
QRegularExpression(R"D("([^"]*)"\s*"([^"]*)")D");
```

I know it matches Pearl and PHP regex.

Comment: How can you differentiate between nested and unnested quotes? If those inside were doubled, it would be possible.

Comment: Do you mean if it was "" nested? That is the problem currently, single quotation pairs are fine.

Comment: Interesting question. I tried with something simple [like this](https://regex101.com/r/eD7uO2/1): `^"(.*?)"\h+"(.*)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"(.*?)"[\t\r ]+"(.*?)"(?=[ ]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/2

Comment: This works for one line, but degrades over multiple. https://regex101.com/r/hR7tH4/1

Comment: Works very well, I did a bit of editing because it would bug out if the double quote pairs were next to each other or if there were other characters after the pairs. https://regex101.com/r/aT9jV1/1

Comment: -I take that back, doesn't do the original purpose, but yours does, so marking it as answer, thank you.